# Filtering an object column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset 100000 rows X 200 columns. I want to perform a classification.
My target column, is an object (string) and has 1345 unique values.

1. Let's suppose that my target column is 'names'. I am interested in keeping just the following names: John, Mary, Chris, Anna. How do I 'filter' my dataset, so that it contains only the rows that have these names in the target column?
2. After filtering the dataset, I want to create a classifier that will have four classes, meaning the four names.I thought about using get_dummies,but then I will have 4 target columns. I just want to transform  for example, John = 1, Mary = 2 , etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.loc` to filter within a column:

```
name_set = {'John', 'Mary', 'Chris', 'Anna'}
res = df.loc[df['names'].isin(name_set)]
```

You can use a dictionary to map your names to numeric identifiers:

```
d = {'John': 1, 'Mary': 2, 'Chris': 3, 'Anna': 4}
res['names'] = res['names'].map(d)
```

The second step can also be implemented using [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/categorical.html) via extracting category codes.

Comment: @apostolos, Excellent, there's a green tick on the left you should click - this indicates to other users that the problem is solved.